# Not able to Run Spring Boot 1.3.0M5

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I tried changing Spring Boot version from 1.2.2 release to 1.3.0M5. while running spring boot run I get following exception. I tried updating the snapshots while building and running but to no avail.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(Abstr
actRunMojo.java:435)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface      org.
springframework.context.ApplicationListener :org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstance
s(SpringApplication.java:385)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstance
s(SpringApplication.java:362)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplicati
on.java:231) 
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.(SpringApplication.j
ava:206)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   org/springframework/context/event/GenericApplicationListener
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstance
s(SpringApplication.java:378) 
.  .. 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:      org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListener
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 23 more
```

Answer (score 3):

You are forcing a different Spring Framework version than the one Spring Boot 1.3 requires.

In general you should let spring boot derives the versions for you and only override when you have a specific problem. Check the documentation on dependencies management for more details.

1.3.0.M5 requires spring framework 4.2.1

Comment: I had earlier overriden that in my pom.xml. But when I upgraded the spring-boot version itself i removed that. I will check again though just to make sure. Actually my project involves other spring-boot starter modules as well could it be related to those starter modules? like I have to upgrade versions of all spring-boot starter modules?

Comment: Of course you do. That's why you shouldn't specify any version of these and let the spring boot dependency management deal with that stuff.